# How to make Laravel not to prolong authentication session automatically?

Tags: php, laravel

By default, Laravel prolongs authentication session when a user just requests any page. I am making an application where session needs to be revalidated after access token has expired, but session never expires as long as you using an application. So how to make session expire anyway, even if you use an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but you could save current time on login for example:

```
session(['login_at' => now()]);
```

Then check it in middleware and logout user if user was logged in more than an hour ago:

```
if (session('login_at') && session('login_at')->lt(now()->subHour())) {
    auth()->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: @AlexeyAlshenetsky also, if you want to clean session, you can do `session()->flush()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to say but check the config/session.php and there you are several php session related configs which you can change.

Check the key 'lifetime'

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

Comment: Session lifetime means that session will be destroyed after X minutes of inactivity. I need to destroy a session even if an user does some activity.